# Android webrtc app doesn't work on different network

Tags: android, webrtc, stun, turn

I have developed an android native app which shares screen with the web dashboard using MediaProjection and WebRTC.

The problem is the app works fine if the android app and the web dashboard is in the same network.

As soon as they are in the different network app didn't work.

I am using Web sockets as a Signaling channel.

The stun server used : `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302`

WebRTC library : `io.pristine:libjingle:11139@aar`

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

On different network you may need TURN server in addition to STUN server. STUN server is used to get external IP, but you may need TURN Server to relay traffic if peer to peer connection fails.

You can find detailed explanation from [link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/#after-signaling-using-ice-to-cope-with-nats-and-firewalls)

It is very hard to find a free TURN server. You can use the [link](http://piratefsh.github.io/projects/2015/08/27/webrtc-stun-turn-servers.html) to deploy your own TURN server